# Duda con formulario DJANGO

Tags: django

estoy creando una aplicación con Django 4.2, en la cual hay un modelo llamado **Terceros** en este modelo se van a crear tanto proveedores como clientes, y hay campos de estos modelos donde solo aplican para proveedores y otros aplican solo para clientes:

```
class Terceros(models.Model):
    tipoTercero = models.ForeignKey(TipoTercero, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tipoDocumento = models.ForeignKey(TipoDocumento, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    numeroDocumento = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=24)

    primerApellido = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    segundoApellido = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    primerNombre = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    otrosNombres = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    municipio = models.ForeignKey(Municipio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    barrio = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    celular = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    correo = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    ciiu = models.ForeignKey(Ciiu, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_ingreso = models.DateField()
 
    estado = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    razonSocial = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    formaPago = models.ForeignKey(FormaPago, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

La duda que tengo es si puedo personalizar el formulario para que el primer campo que seleccione el usuario sea el tipo de usuario y de acuerdo a lo seleccionado se muestren los campos correspondientes a cliente o proveedor.

Anteriormente lo he trabajado con Vistas basadas en funciones, y en el HTML hago las validaciones para mostrar lo que quiero, pero quiero saber si esto mismo lo puedo hacer de otra forma o con las vistas basadas en clase.

Agradezco la atención

Comment: Deberías crear dos clases separadas una para clientes y otra para provedores, y a través del usuario autenticado en la aplicación mostrar el formulario.